# how to add series to chart

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I am trying add a new chart1 sheet and adding series from sheet1 to my chart1 sheet.

Here is my code...

```
Charts.Add
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Closing Price"
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection.XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$741" '<<<<This is the xvalue
    .FullSeriesCollection.Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$741"  '<<<<This are the value 
End With
```

Please tell me how to do this..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the number of the series collection.

```
Charts.Add
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Closing Price"
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$741" '<<<<This is the xvalue
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$741"  '<<<<This are the value
End With
```

By the way, if you took the trouble to fire up the macro recorder, insert a new chart sheet, define new series, then stop the macro recorder, you would see all the commands laid out in full.